# Hibernate Formula not setting value

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, formula

I have this entity

```
@Entity
public class OrderEntity {
   /**
   * Unique id of this order.
   */
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   @Formula(value="(select e.release from environment e where e.name = source_Environment)")
   private String release;

   @Column
   private String sourceEnvironment;
   
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public final class Environment {
@Id
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 4)
private String name;
@Column(name = "RELEASE", nullable = false, length = 4)
private String release;
```

Hibernate produces this query:

```
SELECT orderentity0_.id              AS id1_5_,
    orderentity0_.source_environment AS source_21_5_,
    (SELECT e.release
        FROM environment e
        WHERE e.name = orderentity0_.source_Environment ) AS formula1_
FROM OrderEntity orderentity0_
```

When I execute the query manually against my (db2) database I get the expected results. But when I call orderEntity.getRelease() on the object created by hibernate (OrderEntity), it returns `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I was missing the schema in the formula, so setting it to:

```
   @Formula(value="(select e.release from myschema.environment e where e.name = 
                    source_Environment)")
   private String release;
```

fixed my problem.